# Using of structured data markup with review authority

Tags: seo, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm trying to structured data for producing the review like this on google search (please see the image) -
[image]
According to this [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) I've to write the following structured data markup -

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Super Book"
  },
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Joe"
  },
  "reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "7",
    "bestRating": "10"
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Washington Times"
  }
}
</script>
```

But according to this [link](https://www.hitsearchlimited.com/news/how-can-your-business-get-star-ratings-in-organic-search-results-id0318) I've to get review from a trusted review authority. I'm wondering why we need the structured data markup (where we have static 'rating', 'bestRating' etc value definitely these shouldn't be static) or how we can combine this with trusted review authority for getting dynamic ratting that changes over time?

Comment: I don’t understand your question exactly. Do you ask how to use JSON-LD so that the values get updated accordingly (when a new review comes in, for example)?

Comment: @unor yes, JSON-LD. Thanks

Comment: So it’s not really relevant to this question what kind of structured data you have or what kind of rich snippet you want, if I understand it correctly. Asking how to keep values in JSON-LD up to date is a pure technical question. You would typically do this with a backend programming language (like PHP, or a CMS add-on e.g. for WordPress etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you are confusing two issues. Google requires reviews to be created using Schema markup in order for the review to have a chance to rank directly in the SERPs.

It is the companies that provide reviews: Yelp, Angie's List, Washington Times, etc, that have to format their content management systems to upload user generated review data into the proper markup.

So if you're a web developer working for one of these companies, then it makes sense to code the CMS so that the listings are displayed using schema markup.

If you are the marketer, your job is to get reviews, not format the way they are getting displayed.

There are of course other ways to use Schema markup on your own site to boost organic traffic. Consider for example the first SERP screenshot displayed in this [article](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/get-started-using-schema/).

Here the webmaster has used schema markup to list three upcoming events in their result, which gives them four links in a single listing. This causes the listing to stand out and gives increased incentive for users to click, almost guaranteeing a higher click-thru rate than if they'd have not used the markup.